# Update GUI when data source is updated

Tags: php, database

I want to update my PHP GUI view when my data source is updated(data source can be a database). I'm having a hard time understanding how I can do this without reloading the whole view for the user.

What I try to achieve is:

Users view are shown, from an handheld device call a script on the site and the script updates a data source, when data source is updated, update the users view with this updated data without reloading.

Is this possible with PHP/JS and how would I achieve this? I do not need any code but more step by step explanation and perhaps what technology to use.

Appreciate any suggestion that leads me forward with this problem.

Best regards,

Gabriel Paulsson

Comment: did you watched at the javascript lib named backbone.js? it could help a lot with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to do it just with php, telling the page to update itself at a certain interval.

The way I would do it, is to use javascript with ajax and a timed event. The event fires of an ajax call to the server, the server returns any new information.

If you are new to ajax, you probably want to use a library to make things a bit easier to handle. My personal favourite is prototype.js, although at the moment that seems to be a bit "on the way out" and eg jquery may be a better alternative.

Comment: Problem with this is that the data can come at any time and it should take no longer then a few seconds from that the data source is updated until the person see's it on the screen. I will look up the suggestions you made!

Comment: Will this approach have a heavy load on the server? Sounds heavy to have a timed event asking for data every second. Especially when having multiple users viewing.

Comment: Depends - do you know how many users you'll have? Anyhow, if the alternative is to refresh the entire page, the ajax-call will put a lower load on the server, as less data is to be processed. And also, you can decide how often the server should be polled. As far as I know, there are no possibilites to have the server to "tell" the clients when something is coming in.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax for refreshing data when any event happens. The page will not reload by using ajax. It is very simple to use ajax. Googel, gmail and many other use such ajax. Learn in ten minutes form w3school http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp